# How to create a condition based on URL path with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a transparent menu to the home page only.

How can I do that? I've created a constant called `isHomePage` and now I need to specify a URL (the `index.tsx`) to represent this const.

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const isHomePage = URL('/index');
 
    return (    
        <>
          {!isHomePage && <Navbar />}
          {isHomePage && <TransparentNavbar />}
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: you have created a new URL object, which will do nothing to help you. you need to get the current window location and check to see if its value corresponds to your homepage.

Comment: I'm a newbie, can you help me with that?

Comment: ```const { asPath } = useRouter(); const isHomePage = asPath === '/';``` Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter

Comment: As @brc-dd mentioned, you'll want to use NextJS's included `useRouter` hook to get the current path.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it without `isHomePage`

Not sure if it's the best practice, but it looks pretty clean and seems to be a straightforward solution.

I have accomplished it with next.js `useRouter()` hook.

`Navbar.jsx` component

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Navbar() {

const router = useRouter();

// This piece of code checks if your route is home->'/'
if(router.pathname==='/'){
    // returns nothing -> null
    return null;
};

return <>YOUR COMPONENT</>;
```

}

`TransparentNavbar.jsx` component

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function TransparentNavbar() {

    const router = useRouter();

    // This piece of code checks if your route is home->'/'
    if(router.pathname==='/'){
        // returns TransparentNavbar -> null
        return <>YOUR COMPONENT</>;
    };
    
    // if it's not home page -> returns nothing
    return null;    
 }
```

`_app.js` component

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {    

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <TransparentNavbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
    ); 
}

export default MyApp;
```